# Convert a non generic class with generic methods to a generic class

Tags: java, string, class, generics, methods

The title may be confusing...here is the code:

This is the class generate each different object with different type..such as: `BookingReferenceExtractor` `AircraftExtractor` the method I have here is generic... take a string and return different objects subjectively...

```
public class ExtractorFactory {

    private static ExtractorFactory extractorFactory;

    public ExtractorFactory(){

    }

    public Extractor extractorFor(String extractorType) {
        if(extractorType.equals("booking_reference")){
            return new BookingReferenceExtractor();
        }
        else if("itinerary".equals(extractorType)){
            return new ItineraryExtractor();
        }
        else if("passengers".equals(extractorType))
        {
            return new PassengersExtractor();
        }
        else if("aircraft".equals(extractorType))
        {
            return new AircraftExtractor();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

What I need now is to make the class to be generic...for example, when I pass a param to constructor, it'll generate object subjectively... without access other methods..
something like:

```
ExtractorFactory BookingReferenceExtractor_object = new ExtractorFactory("booking_reference");

ExtractorFactory ItineraryExtractor_object = new ExtractorFactory("itinerary");
..
..
```

Basically, need to do something with the class contractor, to make it generic, any string passed in, it can generate accordinate object straight way without calling other methods.

I've been reading this tut: http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c10/s5.html I know it should be doing something like:

```
class Queue<T> {
    private LinkedList<T> items = new LinkedList<T>();
    public void enqueue(T item) {
      items.addLast(item);
    }
    public T dequeue() {
      return items.removeFirst();
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
      return (items.size() == 0);
    }
}
```

...but not sure exactly how to convert to a generic class... any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: With all of the source code, this question is very hard to read, follow, understand, or answer.  Because of this, I have voted to close this question as "too localized" since it is unlikely to be useful to a future visitor.  Please try to break the question down into something simpler and shorter.

Comment: You're not going to get much out of using generics here. You would be better off studying `enum`s and using them here.